# Samsung logo has gone and was replaced by "Welcome" message

Tags: boot

Yesterday my phone's Samsung logo has gone and was replaced by "WELCOME" message each time I've booted my phone. I don't know why it happened. Also the Samsung shutdown logo was replaced by "BYEBYE" message. I search for the solution and this is what I've did: I've rooted my phone and I went to System/media and looked for the file that contain Welcome and Byebye messages, I found them in bootanimation2.zip and shutdownanimation2.zip so I delete them including their bootaudio.mp3' and shutdownaudip.mp3. No more left in the System/media except for samsunganimation and samsung shutdown animation So when I rebooted my phone the Samsung logo has been restored including the Samsung shutdown logo, the BYEBYE message has disappeared but the "Welcome" logo continued to showed up each time I started my phone. ...Where can I find the exact location of this logo? I know it is no longer in System/Media because I could not find it there anymore Any help will be appreciated Thanks

Comment: It's a Chinese phone?

Comment: Did this start happening **after** you rooted the phone? Sounds like the rooting process might have left a couple of extra helpers. What steps did you follow to root the phone?

Comment: @Dan Hulme This happened before I rooted my phone. I suspected that it came from system update. because when I find this changes one steps I've made is i scan my cellphone using Malwarebytes the result shows that my phone was infected with trojan dropper. I think the name was something like fakewirelessupdate. I removed this malware by rooting my phone.

Comment: @DanHulme The steps I've made in rooting my phone are: 1)  I installed Kingo root 2) in ES file explorer I change the permission from RO to RW then I went to System/media and look for the file with "welcome" and "Byebye" logo and then I delete them. I know the "welcome logo" was no longer there because I search the media folder and I could no longer find it there, so I suspect that there is another copy of this logo located in another folder somewhere in android system but I don't where it was.

Comment: @esQmo_ yes I think its made in china

Comment: With chinese Samsung clones, boot animation can be changed by key combo, sometimes holding volume up or down while powering the phone changes the boot animation. There are also some short code that you can dial to change the animation